Compile error due to being unable to find ncurses library when compiling in MSYS2 environment
I am trying to compile Vim from source with Ruby support for the command-t plugin in an MSYS2 environment (using the UCRT64 shell). So I followed the instructions of the Vim website and used git to download the source files of Vim into a folder named "vim", and then after uncommenting a few lines in vim/src/auto/configure (in order to enable compiling with Ruby), I tried running ./configure, but it fails with checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!.
I managed to fix this error by declaring LDFLAGS="-L/usr/include -L/usr/lib" and passing -with-tlib=ncurses to the configure script. This allows it to pass the tgetent check (actually it seems to just skip the check if you do this), but it just fails further down the line with:
checking --with-tlib argument... ncurses
checking for linking with ncurses library... configure: error: FAILED

which isn't much improvement.
Things I have tried:

Confirmed that the shared ncurses library files exists. I did ls "/usr/lib" | grep "libncurses" and it outputs:

libncurses++w.a
libncurses++w.dll.a
libncurses.a
libncurses.dll.a
libncursesw.a
libncursesw.dll.a


Confirmed that the ncurses source files also exists (I got them by installing the ncurses-devel package). ls "/usr/include/ncurses" | grep "ncurses" outputs:

ncurses.h
ncurses_dll.h


Declared LDFLAGS="-L/usr/include -L/usr/lib" to point the compile script to the shared ncurses libraries, and LIBS="-l/usr/include/ncurses/ncurses.h" to point the compile script to the ncurses header file.
Declared vim_cv_tgetent=zero, because I read somewhere that this can resolve problems compiling with curses. I believe I read it in some StackExchange answer, but I can't find it now.
Replaced the ncurses argument to -with-tlib to the full path to libncurses.a (which is /usr/lib/libncurses.a), instead of just the name of the library.
Replaced LIBS="-l/usr/include/ncurses/ncurses.h" with LIBS="-l/usr/include/ncurses/ncurses_dll.h".
Countless different combinations of steps 3, 4, 5, & 6 (including all at the same time). There seems to be no difference whatsoever, and the compile always fail at the step checking for linking with ncurses library....

I also do make distclean between attempts (as the Vim website recommends), so the problem can't be caused by out-of-date caches from previous failed compiles.
I have tried searching online, and found a lot of similiar questions on various StackExchange sites (such as this), but none of their answers helped solve this problem.
Here are all the packages I installed for the sake of compiling Vim:
make
automake1.16
ruby
ncurses-devel
msys2-runtime-devel
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc
cscope

A weird thing I noticed is that the configure script outputs checking for CYGWIN or MSYS environment... no even though I am in an MSYS2 environment. I thought maybe this is what's causing the problem, but reading the output of ./configure --help, there doesn't seem to be an option to tell it you're in a MSYS2 environment.

"Command-t" that's a name I haven't heard in a while. Anyway, the "vim" package already includes the ruby interpreter so why bother?

@romainl Oh, I didn't realize Vim already checks for the presense of Ruby and loads it if available. The last time I tried, I haven't installed the "Ruby" package yet, and I just assumed you had to build from source to enable it, instead of installing it and seeing if Vim detects it. Guess I don't need to build from source after all.

But still, is Vim supposed to be this hard to compile from source? What if in the future, I encounter a feature that actually can only be enabled by re-compiling?

Package managers and ready-made executables exist for a reason: compiling a program manually can be hard and time consuming. It should be the last thing you try. "What if…?" You will see when you get there.

I would follow the msys2 compilation steps

Oh! I didn't realize Msys2 had their own custom procedure for compiling Vim. That explains all the weird errors when trying to use Vim's normal configure script I guess.

@romainl Yeah, now that I know Vim automatically checks for the presence of Ruby (why didn't I think of testing that...), I can proceed without compiling it myself. Thanks :)

For msys2/mingw (or ucrt) do not use configure script. Instead, make -f Make_ming.mak should be run, as written in READMEs.
P.S. Actually, I've only ever compiled Vim under mingw64, but I believe ucrt64 works mostly the same.

...as written in READMEs Ahh, I see I'm stupid now. After reading the git help page on the Vim website, I assumed that was everything to know, and didn't think of checking the official Github repo to see if it had README files. Reading them now, there's a lot of detailed compilation instructions for every platform, including Msys2 and Cygwin. And it also tells you you're supposed to use Make-ming.mak when building for Msys2.

But that compiles a Windows version, I thought the OP wanted a MSYS2 version?

@ChristianBrabandt Then he wrote "ucrt64 shell", so this is native Windows version.

ah, I wondered what that is supposed to be....

@ChristianBrabandt Of course, this is still the same bash/mintty but with different environment preset. So compilers and tools in use are different.
